# Inserting records found in one table to another table based on criteria

Tags: php, mysql

I've been mulling this over for weeks.  Nothing I'm doing seems to work.

I've got two tables, Payroll, and Payroll_Worksheet.  Payroll has a column named Monitoring_Period.  Payroll_Worksheet has a column named MT_End_Date.  They are both VARCHAR fields.  WID is a unique index which autoincrements when the Payroll_Worksheet table is added to.

I have the following code:

```
$sql = "SELECT WID, Payroll_Worksheet.DSA, Payroll.Hours, Payroll.Total, right(Payroll.Monitoring_Period, 9), MT_End_Date FROM `Payroll_Worksheet` inner join Payroll on Client_ID = DSA where MT_End_Date = right(Monitoring_Period,9);";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $WID = $row['WID'];
    $addhr[$row[WID]] += $row['Hours'];
    $addpy[$row[WID]] += $row['Total'];
    $myhr = $addhr[$row[WID]];
    $mytot = $addpy[$row[WID]];

    echo $myhr . "<br>";
    echo $mytot . "<br>";

    $updater = "update Payroll_Worksheet set Hours = $myhr, Current_Hourly_Pay = $mytot where WID = '$WID'";
    mysqli_query($con,$updater);
```

My problem is that my Payroll_Worksheet table isn't getting populated properly.  Some of the Hours fields that match from the Payroll table aren't getting over to the Payroll_Worksheet table.

Any help would be appreciated, and if you need any additional information, please let me know.